# calculate time to arrive in a procedure

Tags: delphi, time, date-arithmetic

I want to determine necessary time to execute a procedure,  time value must be returned in  the first instruction in this procedure, like this:

```
 procedure  myProcedure;
 begin
 // determine necessary time here
 //other instructions
 end;
```

First, of all, is this possible? if yes, how can I do this?
Thanks for your replies

Comment: To be clear -- you want, at the beginning of the procedure, to predict how long the remainder of the procedure will take to complete?  Is that correct?  Out of curiosity...why?

Comment: Yes that's what I want, why? because I need this value to calculate the progress position of progressBar in a timer ^^.

Comment: Deciding how long something will take is usually a dynamic exercise, not the least because every computer will be different.  It depends heavily on what you are doing - disk I/O, network, calculations, etc... each could benefit from a different strategy.  This becomes more complicated if the code is branchy (ie : lots of conditionally executed paths).  If you are iterating, a typical approach is to start timing and then estimate completion based on time taken and the percentage of the work complete at present.  Without seeing your code, it's difficult to suggest more.

Comment: I'm doing a bike race tonight. I'd like to know in advance how long I will take. I think I've got as much chance of getting an answer as you do. In short, what you are asking for is impossible in general. What you typically do is measure progress in iterations, or bytes, rather than time. You know if you have 250 tasks to do, and each task is of similar size, that after completing 50 tasks you are 20% through the total job. To know exactly how you should do this requires knowledge of what `//other instructions` actually hides.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Impossible to be precise, certainly.  Reasonable and approximate running estimates are usually not so difficult.  I am guessing OP is after the latter.

Comment: @J... Including variation in processor speed, network speed, disk speed, memory speed? Not at all easy in general. Proportion of work done approach is easy enough because that automatically normalises to the host environment.

Comment: You could apply a heuristic (self-learning) system to predict the time.

Comment: It will also depend on the rest of the ongoing activities in the system. Other higher priority processes might take away CPU time.
The hardware and possibly even the software environment would need to be constrained very much in order to make this possible.
(Not like in the good old C64 era ... :) )

Also a progress bar does not have to be necessarily associated with time, it is worth considering that total/accomplished work used to do the job.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I agree that proportion of work done is the most sensible approach - I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.  Your original comment said only that this was an impossible task (without suggestion of an approach to follow) - obviously your later edit changes the apparent meaning of my comment.

Comment: This is the kind of things that **profilers** are meant for.  Don't have your code try to time itself.  Let a profiler run the code and time it for you.  Then the profiler can analyze the recorded times and tell you what you need to know about it.

Comment: @Remy What happens when you want to run the program on a machine for which you don't have profile data?

Answer (score 2):

In general you cannot expect to do this. Unless you have carefully profiled the code on the machine on which you run it, under the exact conditions in which it runs. Without that information there's no way to reliably predict run time up front.

You actually want to display progress. Typically you do that by keeping track of how the overall task is progressing. If the task is made up of 50 similarly sized sub tasks, then you can measure proportion complete simply by knowing how many sub tasks are complete.

That's the normal way to measure progress for a progress bar. If you wish to estimate time to completion then make a note of when the task starts. Then, as worl proceeds, you can use simple maths to work out an estimate of the time remaining. If the first 10 sub tasks took 30 seconds, then estimate that the next 10 will take another 30 seconds.